# How to load a python module com.foo2.bar when there are two different locations with top level directory as com

Tags: python-module

I have modules at two different locations

e.g

```
Location1
   |- com
       |-__init__.py
       |-foo1
          |-__init__.py
          |-bar1.py

Location2
   |- com
       |-__init__.py
       |-foo2
          |-__init__.py
          |-bar2.py
```

The two locations are in the PYTHONPATH, in the above order. When I try to import com.foo2.bar2, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named foo2
```

If I change the top-level package name to com2 (i.e location2/com2/foo2/bar2.py), then the import statement succeeds.

I think I am doing something incorrect, could someone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called namespace packages in Python.  One way to do them with the standard library is to use [pkgutil](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil#pkgutil.extend_path); another way is to use the third-party module [pkg_resources](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#namespace-packages) provided by the distribute or setuptools projects.

Support for namespace packages will be improved in the standard library and interpreter with PEP 382.

Answer (score 0):

It seems python import mechanism doesn't support splitting of a single package into multiple source trees.

We achieve this using bootstrapping through Python's import hooks PEP 302: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/